# Prevent connected socket from closing in Python

Tags: python, sockets

I have simple function that act like a **client**. It sents an event message and wait for an ack(I removed that part for simplicity). After that it'll get receive more messages:

```
def send_data(message):
    """Connect to server and get requests"""
    sock = socket.socket()
    host = 'localhost'
    port = 8000
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((host,port))

    try:
        if message:
            sock.sendall(message)

        # Look for the response
        has_request = False
        while not has_request:
            data = sock.recv(1024)

            #First I get ACK, code not listed here...
            #Next iteration, I got my request message
            has_request = True

    finally:
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Closing socket'
        sock.close() 

    return data
```

I call this in the `__main__` statement:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_data = send_data(event)

    if server_data:
        parse_request(server_data)
```

However I need to prevent the socket to be closed automatically. Because I have to sent another messagea after I parsed the request. I removed the sock.close() but the socket still get closed. Is this because I'm returing the data and I'm out of the functions scope?

I just want to connect, and then receive and sent messages without any problems, at any time in my program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you go outside the `send_data` method, your socket `sock` will no longer be referenced by anybody, so the garbage collector will do his job and delete the object, that will consequently close the socket (even without the `close()` call).

If you return the socket object with your data and get it in your main part, the socket will be still referenced and not closed.

```
def create_socket():
    sock = socket.socket()
    host = 'localhost'
    port = 8000
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((host,port))
    return sock

def send_data(message, sock):
    """Get requests"""
    if message:
        sock.sendall(message)

    # Look for the response
    has_request = False
    while not has_request:
        data = sock.recv(1024)

        #First I get ACK, code not listed here...
        #Next iteration, I got my request message
        has_request = True
    return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_sock = create_socket()
    server_data = send_data(event, server_sock)

    if server_data:
        parse_request(server_data, server_sock)

    #no more use of server_socket ? 
    server_sock.close()
```

Comment: Then it is a better approach to return the socket and to the socket.recv and socket.sendall in other function?

Comment: @FatihArslan : maybe the better approach would be to put the socket management in a object/function that will create the socket and then give it to who need this socket :)

Comment: I creat a new sockeet Class to make it much more easier. Thanks for the answer :)